# showing error in visual studio code

Tags: vb.net

this code showing if google.com is not open then open yahoo.com 
mean if 1st site is not working then 2nd site open automaticly

but i dont know what is the problem in that visual studio showing error

End Of Statement Expected

can anybody tell me how can i fix this issue 
please help me to fix this issue
thanks

this is my complete code

Public Class Form1

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      try webbrowser1.navigate("www.google.com")
      catch ex As exception webbrowser1.navigate("www.yahoo.com")
        End Try


    End Sub


    Private Sub Back_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Back.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoBack()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Forward_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Forward.Click
        WebBrowser1.GoForward()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.Stop()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.GoHome()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Application.Exit()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a carriage return after the Try :

```
    Try
        webbrowser1.navigate("www.google.com")
    Catch ex As Exception
        webbrowser1.navigate("www.yahoo.com")
    End Try
```